# A way to work on web projects with others without over writing files.. etc

Tags: php, web-applications, editor

I am a web freelancer and had been doing all coding by myself using netbeans (set up to use a remote server (ftp)).

Recently, I started working with 2 other guys.   They help me with php and css.  The problem is that sometimes we want to work at the same time.  Obviously one can immediately see the problems were having.  Files being over writting / lost.

What do you recommend we do?  Is there something like netbeans that allows checking in and out of files.  I like netbeans as my editor and would prefer to keep it.

To give you a little extra information on our workflow.  Usually I set up a dev site (generally a subdomain, dev.site.com) and a live site (site.com).  All work is done on the dev site which I then move to live site once all is finished.  I never use localhost sites.

Also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surely you need a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) (amongst others) integrate fairly well with Netbeans.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use some versioning system to prevent data loss.

- [Git](http://git-scm.com/)
- [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System)
- [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/)

Other option is to use some file locking system.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at some [source code management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control#Source_management_models) tools. Netbeans supports at least [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_%28software%29) and [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System). They should be listed under the `Team` menu. It has a [FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansUserFAQ#Version_Control_Systems) on which it supports

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [Github](http://github.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Assembla provides a free SVN hosting for collaborative projects.